# Cleaning up Jetty - Removing 'unnecessaries' things

Tags: java, jetty

I'm used to use [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) as my web container.

What I did on my **install steps** is get the original tar ball and **cleanup some directories and files** from it.

**What I want to raise here, is:**

> What are you used to remove from Jetty to use on production/staging enviroments?

**What I CHANGE on default jetty package:**

- **REMOVE**:

  - README.txt
  - pom.xml
  - javadoc/
  - examples/
  - /webapps/test*
  - /contexts/test*
  - /project-website
  - /resources/log4j.properties
- **CREATE**:

  - work/

**Questions:**

- I'm not breaking any license right?
- Can I bring any drawback for my system (performance/stability) doing that?
- Does anyone customize more than this on jetty?
- Comments?
- Questions?
- Tips?

**Related posts:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486449/redistributing-jetty

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not breaking any license right?

Correct.

> Can I bring any drawback for my system (performance/stability) doing that?

The only drawback is that the Log4J properties file is useful for controlling how much (or how little) logging is performed. Disabling logging altogether results in smaller log files, conserving disk space. (Shouldn't be an issue with TB drives.) If the logging properties file cannot be found, an application might default to `DEBUG` or `INFO` levels, rather than `ERROR` levels. So, Log4J is useful to tell all applications to only log critical information.

Eliminating extraneous examples (the test suite) tightens security by exposing less system information. It can also save a bit of memory because the test webapps cannot get loaded into memory.

> Does anyone customize more than this on jetty?

You can clean the `webapps` directory as follows:

```
cd /opt/jetty
rm -rf webapps
mkdir -p webapps/root
echo "<html><body></body></html>" > webapps/root/index.html
```

Restart Jetty.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I was thinking that this post could have a lot of comments! I'm used to cleanup jetty! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of cleaning up Jetty (9.1.5).

```bash
tar -xzvf jetty-distribution-9.1.5.v20140505.tar.gz
# can rename 'jetty-distribution-9.1.5.v20140505' to 'jetty-9.1.5' or similar
cd jetty-distribution-9.1.5.v20140505
rm -rf VERSION.txt license-eplv10-aslv20.html notice.html start.d/jsp.ini resources/log4j.properties demo-base/
find -name README.TXT | xargs rm -fv

mv etc etc.bak              # keep a backup of etc/ and modules/, take whats necessary
mv modules modules.bak
mkdir etc modules work
mv modules.bak/.donotdelete modules.bak/deploy.mod modules.bak/ext.mod modules.bak/http.mod \
    modules.bak/logging.mod modules.bak/resources.mod modules.bak/security.mod modules.bak/server.mod modules.bak/servlet* \
    modules.bak/webapp.mod modules/
mv $(grep -h --color=none "etc.*.xml" modules/* | sed 's/etc/etc\.bak/g') etc/
mv etc.bak/jetty-started.xml etc.bak/jetty.conf etc/        # required for bin/jetty.sh
mv etc.bak/webdefault.xml etc/                              # required for web applications
                                                            # provides default deployment descriptor config for all apps
# rm -rf modules.bak/ etc.bak/                              # remove if not needed

sed -i '/^#/d; /^\s*$/d' start.ini start.d/http.ini         # clean if needed

vi start.ini start.d/http.ini                               # check and modify if needed
    start.ini: 'jetty.send.server.version=false', remove '--module=websocket'
    http.ini: 'jetty.port=9999'
vi modules/<whatever.mod>                                   # check and modify if needed
vi etc/jetty.xml # to prevent Jetty from showing context related information
    remove
        <Item>
            <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
        </Item>
vi etc/jetty-logging.xml # suffix date with '-', instead of prefixing with '_'
    change
        <Arg><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log</Arg>
        ...
        <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
    to
        <Arg><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/stderrout.log.yyyy_mm_dd</Arg>
        ...
        <Arg type="java.lang.String">yyyy-MM-dd</Arg>
        <Arg type="java.lang.String">HHmmssSSS</Arg>
        <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
vi etc/webdefault.xml # disable jsp support and modify other default settings
    remove or comment out <servlet> and <servlet-mapping> of JSP Servlet
    remove or comment out index.jsp from <welcome-file-list>
    set dirAllowed to false in default servlet
vi bin/jetty.sh # use $JETTY_BASE/logs instead of $JETTY_BASE as working directory
    change
        JETTY_RUN=$(findDirectory -w /var/run /usr/var/run $JETTY_BASE /tmp)
        JETTY_STATE=$JETTY_BASE/${NAME}.state
    to
        JETTY_RUN=$(findDirectory -w /var/run /usr/var/run $JETTY_BASE/logs $JETTY_BASE /tmp)
        JETTY_STATE=$JETTY_RUN/${NAME}.state
vi bin/jetty.sh # use $JETTY_HOME/work as default TMPDIR
    move following 
        TMPDIR=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}
    below 'JETTY_HOME=$PWD' and change
        TMPDIR=${TMPDIR:-"$JETTY_HOME"/work}
```

And the resulting structure.

```
jetty-distribution-9.1.5.v20140505
├── bin
│   └── jetty.sh
├── etc
│   ├── jetty-deploy.xml
│   ├── jetty-http.xml
│   ├── jetty-logging.xml
│   ├── jetty-started.xml
│   ├── jetty.conf
│   ├── jetty.xml
│   └── webdefault.xml
├── lib
│   └── <no change or keep only relevant>
├── logs
├── modules
│   ├── deploy.mod
│   ├── ext.mod
│   ├── http.mod
│   ├── logging.mod
│   ├── resources.mod
│   ├── security.mod
│   ├── server.mod
│   ├── servlet.mod
│   ├── servlets.mod
│   └── webapp.mod
├── resources
├── start.d
│   └── http.ini
├── start.ini
├── start.jar
├── webapps
└── work
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past I used to trim Jetty down **a lot** by cutting out all the frameworks I don't use. That also let me trim down all the dependency jars. Once I got it trimmed down to the bare essentials I used it was very tiny. Then I repackaged it with **onejar** so it was a single file transfer that is ready to execute.  Its been a long time since I managed any large scale application clusters so there are probably better ways to accomplish the same ends. **Cloud computing** comes to mind, but I haven't done much there, but that is where I'd look first if I were facing the same challenges today.

Plus bandwidth and disk are a lot cheaper these days so the problems have gotten smaller with time in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I was feeling alone here on this post! But stop kidding could you remember in more details what do you used to trim on jetty? Cheers!